# How to update Geo location center and marker with latitude and longitude in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I'm using PrimeNG plug-ins(import {GMapModule} from 'primeng/gmap';) in angular 6, and want to display 'google map' with updated latitude and longitude values.

Comment: can you show us what you have tried in stackblitz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

import {GMapModule} from 'primeng/gmap';
This module is working fine to display map, marker, polygon, polyline, circle...But 
not update the center with updated coordinates. I tried following way.

Step 1:- Install Google Maps types for typescript support.

Run command **npm install — save @types/googlemaps**

Step 2:- Link Google Maps JavaScript CDN inside index.html

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Step 3: Next, let’s add a placeholder  for GMap in "component.html"

```
<div #gmap style=”width:100%;height:400px”></div>
<button pButton type="button" label="Click" (click)="showMap($event)"> 
</button>
```

Step 4: In component.ts

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { } from '@types/googlemaps';
(or)
/// <reference types="googlemaps" />


export class AppComponent {  
    @ViewChild('gmap') gmapElement: any;
    map: google.maps.Map;


     showMap(value){
         var mapProp = {
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude),
         zoom: 15,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        // set center
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, mapProp);

        // take marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude),
        title: value.street + " " + value.city + " " + value.country.name
        });
        // set marker
        marker.setMap(this.map);
    }
}
```